# Elementary OS freezes during use

Tags: release-freya

When i'm using normally the system then the system freezes in screen that i'm using, by example : a browser open , or whatever application open..

Then I need restart the computer to use then again, after a time he freezes again ..

I'm using Elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 Built on Ubuntu 14.04

And my pc configs are:

- RAM : 1.9GB
- Processor : Dual-Core Pentium® Dual-Core CPU E5400 2.70GHz
- Graphics : Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Before I used the Elementary Luna and don't happened this.

Comment: You could install Loki. It's the latest version of elementaryOS and may solve your issue again. Maybe yes maybe no. https://elementary.io

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to have any idea how to diagnose this based on the information you've provided. There are thousands of people using Elementary OS without this problem and probably quite a few on very similar specs. The best thing you can do is to run `dmesg` to check what's wrong, just run it in a terminal. When the system freezes, you can also hit ctrl+alt+F1 to enter a tty, and run `top` to see if a process is hogging your CPU, maybe try restart pantheon (window manager) to see if that helps clear it up.

Short of the above, you should ensure that your drivers for your graphics card are installed correctly, and that you're only using applications which are built for your version of the software.

I know this isn't strictly an answer, but the question is very open ended and impossible to answer - I wouldn't be able to fit this information sensibly into a comment. If you find something interesting in dmesg, or if you find that restarting pantheon itself helps, drop a comment on this answer and I'll try provide more information for how to isolate the exact cause.